# Update Entity using Doctrine in Symfony

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, controller, sql-update, patch

I want to update values in my Entity using PATCH method, but when I try to do that, doctrine create new record in table, but do not update. For example I want to update name attribute, so I send this JSON array (in url I send id of the record: api.test/item/{id}):

```
{
   "name": "newname"
}
```

My Controller:

```
public function updateItemAction(Request $request, $id)
{
    $serializer = $this->get('jms_serializer');

    $content = $request->getContent();

    $item = $serializer->deserialize($content,Item::class,'json');

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->getRepository(Item::class)->find($id);
    $em->persist($item);
    $em->flush();
    return new View("updated!",Response::HTTP_OK);
}
```

Comment: Can you copy / pase $item result ( `$serializer->deserialize($content,Item::class,'json')` ). Do you have `setInitialized = false` ?

Comment: What version of Symfony is this? Can you post your controller method annotations as well?

Comment: @Gaylord.P var_dump result after deserialization: `object(AppBundle\Entity\Item)#493 (4) { ["id":"AppBundle\Entity\Item":private]=> NULL ["name":"AppBundle\Entity\Item":private]=> string(9) "oldupdate" ["categories":protected]=> NULL ["attributes":protected]=> NULL } {"name":"oldupdate"}`

Comment: @ASOlivieri Symfony 3.4, method: PATCH

Answer (score 0):

You must withdraw the persist method from your code and it will work better.

Comment: What then will be recorded in the database? I'm looking for the ID and I want to insert what I got after deserialization. If I delete the persist, I will not write anything, since I'm just looking for the ID and using flush.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the merge() function? This allows you to merge the entity into the database, updating the existing entity. Call this function instead of persist. Here is a guide
https://www.vivait.co.uk/labs/updating-entities-when-an-insert-has-a-duplicate-key-in-doctrine

Comment: When I try to update my entity with merge, nothing happens, but if I send JSON with id: `{"id":1, "name": "newname"}` and then merge, everything works fine. But I need to send ID in the URL.

Comment: Could you set the id on you object once its been deserialized? I don't think you need to query for the existing object, just set the id and call merge should do the trick!

Comment: You could try using a method on the entity like this
    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;

        return $this;
    }
But it may cause issues with doctrine due to how it handles ids, so it would need test. Are you unable to alter the request to parse the id in the body rather than URL? If you are not able to you could always add the id to request content by JSON decoding, adding the element to the array and reencoding before deserializing. Hope this helps!